# Using SharePoint to Email or Gather Replies

Tags: sharepoint-online

here is what we are trying to get done and I'm curious if it is even possible.

We want to use a centralized share point page as our main source of communication between liaisons and staff. The liaison for a specific region would be able to utilize the share point page to send out an "Email" to a specific person and maybe either get replies that would show up in a designated thread?

I'm thinking they won't be able to reply to the email and it automatically post to the forum, but maybe include a link that this person can click on at the bottom of the email to respond to the thread?

It would be great if they could reply to the email and that data would post in reply to the thread.

I'm just trying to find an easy way for these liaisons to be able to communicate to their regions and their regions to communicate back without having to give special access to everyone and create 100 different email accounts that are only temporary.

Any suggestions/advice would be great.

Comment: Check out this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/733164/How-to-create-HelpDesk-on-SharePoint-Online